# disable select widget wheel in ipad and use the normal select

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

in ipad the select tag is showed in pop up in a widget wheel. I want to use the normal select tag abd disable that feature in ios . Check this link to understand better what i mean : http://alvinalexander.com/iphone/iphone-ipad-html-select-widget-wheel .

Comment: you can show the picker on actionsheet..

Answer (score 0):

see the following code hope it will help you...enjoy code

```
   -(void)showPicker{

    UIToolbar *toolPicker = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    toolPicker.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(hidePicker)];

    [toolPicker setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelButton,  nil]];

    pickerCategory = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
    pickerCategory.delegate=self;
    pickerCategory.dataSource=self;
    pickerCategory.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    txtCategory.inputView=pickerCategory;
    [pickerCategory addSubview:toolPicker];

    CGRect thePickerFrame = pickerCategory.frame;
    thePickerFrame.origin.y = toolPicker.frame.size.height;
    [pickerCategory setFrame:thePickerFrame];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [view addSubview:pickerCategory];
     [view addSubview:toolPicker];

    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [vc setView:view];
    [vc setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(320, 260)];

    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];


    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:txtCategory.bounds inView:txtCategory permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];


}
-(IBAction)hidePicker{
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```